# Laravel how to integrate TwitterOAuth

Tags: twitter, oauth, laravel

Is there a simple way to integrate TwitterOAuth in laravel?

I'd want to use it like

```
session_start();
require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library

$twitteruser = "twitterusername";
$notweets = 30;
$consumerkey = "12345";
$consumersecret = "123456789";
$accesstoken = "123456789";
$accesstokensecret = "12345";

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

echo json_encode($tweets);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"repositories": [
       {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "kertz/twitteroauth",
                "version": "master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "http://github.com/kertz/twitteroauth",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "classmap": ["."]
                }
            }
        }
    ],

"require": {
        "kertz/twitteroauth": "dev-master"
},
```

it seems to work :)

https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/issues/142